# Telerik Extension for Visiual Studio for javascript functions go to definition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, telerik

which telerik extension is used for the visiual studio that helps in function navigation by f12. and do other similar tasks for javascript?
I work on angularjs and I do need that for me.
Thanksin Advance

Comment: This should be in-build in VS (works in 2017 for me)

Comment: can you please name it?